# Соответствие типов в xml и в ms sql

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server

Есть ли функция которая переводит тип из xml(xsd) в соответствующий ему тип в ms sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция вряд ли. Но есть [таблица](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190942(v=sql.105).aspx), на которую можно опереться при создании своей функции.

Comment: А как быть с `pattern` ?